# Связывание таблиц Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Я пытаюсь создать две таблицы в postgresql:
Одна таблица

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
      ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
      name VARCHAR(255),
);
```

То есть у нее есть просто одно поле name

Другая таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE subcategories (
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  categoryId INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY (categoryId) REFERENCES categories (ID)
);
```

То есть я хочу связать эти таблицы через поле categoryId.
Добавляю данные в первую таблицу:

```
INSERT INTO categories (name)
VALUES
('Давление'),
('Уровень'),
('Температура'),
('ОВК (HVAC)'),
('Расход'),
('Аксессуары');
```

все в порядке. добавляю данные во вторую:

```
INSERT INTO subcategories (name, categoryId)
VALUES
('Датчики давления общепромышленные', 1),
('Датчики давление расплава', 1);
```

Ошибка: ERROR:  insert or update on table "subcategories" violates foreign key constraint "subcategories_categoryid_fkey"
как мне правильно организовать связь и добавить данные? Может быть, вообще не нужна эта связь, просто по значению categoryid фильтровать данные при необходимости?

Comment: Ну а есть ID = 1 в таблице `categories`?

Comment: select * from categories  - в студию результат

Comment: Спасибо, там действительно не было  id 1: ` SELECT * FROM categories;
 id |    name     
----+-------------
  9 | Давление
 10 | Уровень
 11 | Температура
 12 | ОВК (HVAC)
 13 | Расход
 14 | Аксессуары ` так получилось, что нумерация началась не с 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> добавляю данные во вторую:
>
> ```sql
> INSERT INTO subcategories (name, categoryId)
> VALUES
> ('Датчики давления общепромышленные', 1),
> ('Датчики давление расплава', 1);
> ```

Вот это - задание ID от фонаря - НЕПРАВИЛЬНО.

Следует использовать запрос типа:

```sql
WITH cte (s_name, name) AS (
    SELECT 'Датчики давления общепромышленные', 'Давление'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Датчики давления расплава', 'Давление'
)
INSERT INTO subcategories (name, categoryId)
SELECT cte.s_name, categories.ID
FROM cte
JOIN categories USING (name);
```

Т.е. использовать для установления связи ИЗВЕСТНОЕ значение, в данном случае наименование категории.

Comment: Спасибо! Я только начала изучать базы данных, буду знать!

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогли комментарии, у меня действительно не было id = 1:

```
SELECT * FROM categories;
id | name 
----+------------- 
9  | Давление 
10 | Уровень 
11 | Температура 
12 | ОВК (HVAC) 
13 | Расход 
14 | Аксессуары
```